# Auth redirects to wrong path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angular-routing

I have this strange behaviour on my AngularFire Auth function.
The user logs in with email+password and on success it should redirect to /dash, but is redirecting to /home.
/dash is locked for unauth and work as expected, but when I log in and are being redirected to /home, if I type /dash in the browser it's accessible. So, it IS working but my redirecting behaviour is obviously wonky. Also it seems like it's trying to access /dash because it flickers by quickly before sending me to /home on successful login.

I'm using latest Angular + AngularFire + Firebase.
I've tried to set up a plunkr-view of it but it seems to be something with plunkr and firebase that doesn't work.

Anyhow, here's my auth code and my route code, all ideas are welcome!

```
app.controller('loginController', ['currentAuth', '$scope', '$firebaseAuth', 'Auth', '$location', '$rootScope',
function(currentAuth, $scope, $firebaseAuth, Auth, $location,  $rootScope){
var ref = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com');
$scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

// Login user, if true redirect to dash.html, if false, don't redirect, show error message
$scope.loginUser = function(){
  $scope.auth = Auth;
  $scope.auth.$authWithPassword({
    email:$scope.email,
    password:$scope.password
  }, {
    remember: 'sessionOnly'
  }).then(function(authData) {
    console.log('Logged in as: ', authData.uid);
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
    $rootScope.auth = true;
    $scope.auth = Auth;
    $location.path('/dash.html');
  })
  // If error with login, catch it and prompt it
  }).catch(function(error) {
    $('#signBlock').text(error);
  });
 };
}
]);
```

And routes:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth',
function($rootScope, $location, Auth){
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError',
function(event, next, previous, error){
  if(error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED'){
    console.log('AUTH REQ!')
    $location.path('/home');
  }
});
}]);


// Config for routing
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider

// Route for landing page
.when('/home', {
 templateUrl: '/home.html',
 controller: 'homeController'
})

// Route for login page
.when('/login', {
 templateUrl: '/login.html',
 controller: 'loginController',
 resolve: {
  'currentAuth': ['Auth', function(Auth){
    return Auth.$waitForAuth();
  }]
}
})

// Route for user dashboard
.when('/dash', {
 templateUrl: '/dash.html',
 controller: 'dashController',
 resolve: {
  'currentAuth': ['Auth', function(Auth){
    return Auth.$requireAuth();
  }]
 }
 })

 .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });

}]);
```

Comment: Try changing your location.path to /dash - drop the ".html"

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE oh-my-god. i knew it was something stupid like that! huge thanks!